# glassfish cannot access admin console after upgrade

Tags: console, glassfish, admin, upgrade

I just upgraded my glassfish server by doing asadmin> start-domain --upgrade domainname, now i cannot access the admin console. The applications in the server work fine, but the browser remains blank when trying to get into :4848, no error messages, nothing, just remains blank.

i would appreciate a response to this issue,

Thanks

Comment: Can you look through the logs for any errors from the time you did the upgrade and also any errors that happen when you try to access the admin console now? The logs are in the `glassfish/domains/<domainname>/logs` directory

Answer (score 0):

First thing you might want to try is to verify the correctness of your domain.xml. You can do so by running the following command:

```
asadamin verify-domain-xml
```

If there is some inconsistency in your domain description you'll get a corresponding output.

Also, I've got a similar issue on GlassFish 3.1.2 and verify-domain-xml tests were passing successfully. In my case the problem was caused by cyrillic symbols in some resource descriptions.